# Flash content in webview ignores views above the webview in Cocoa

Tags: flash, cocoa, macos, webview

I've tried to find an answer but I can't find it.

I'm trying to display a view above a WebView. The problem is that when flash content is loaded into the WebView it will cover the other view, just the flash not the text and so fourth around it. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

The green rectangle in this picture is the view I want to have above the flash content. As it is now it's placed under it but above the rest of the WebView.
http://twitpic.com/3fdhlo/full

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because all recent builds of Flash render using Core Animation Layers, rather than the older NSView-drawing system.

What are you really trying to achieve with this floating view? Note that while Cocoa does support overlapping views as of 10.5, they're generally not a great idea because of problems like this.

Comment: The floating view is going to have some controls to let the user interact with the flash content. Almost like the playback controls in quicktime that appears and disappears automatically. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I've have thought you're better off injecting HTML/Javascript to render/run the playback controls

Comment: Maybe that was a bad example. There's no playback controls in the floating view instead it's sort of a browser to be able to find the content to display in the webview. I just want it to behave as it does in quicktime, to overlay the content. Is there a way to overlap two NSWindow to avoid this flash problem?

Comment: I don't entirely follow your logic, but setting the overlay view to be layer-backed should probably do the trick. Can't say I overly recommend it mind!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much :) What do you recommend instead?

Comment: Like I said it's general better to inject HTML/CSS for overlays. WebKit is aware of the content then, and can handle it when scrolling etc.